# How to detect which constructor was used to create instance by Windsor?

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, castle-windsor, castle

I have a class with multiple constructors. Is it possible to detect which constructor Windsor used to create instance?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For class with multiple ctors exists the problem with auto resolving. E.g. I did mistake and forgot to specify a parameter. In this case Windsor may resolve with another ctor and this will be mistake.

Comment: Can you post some code to show why you want to do this? Having constructors which aren't supposed to be used sounds like a design issue more than a Windsor issue.